Logitech bluetooth keyboard with a Samsung tablet - why doesn't the Right Shift-W work?
This is a bit of a weird one - I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite, running Android 14 and One UI 6.1 and I'm connecting to it with a Logitech k380 bluetooth keyboard.
Everything works fine except that I cannot use right_shift-w to get a capital W. The left shift key works fine. I can use the right shift key to get every other letter in the alphabet capitalised except W. Unfortunately with W being on the left side of the keyboard, it really does work best with the right shift key.
The problem happens in different applications, so it appears to be something on the keyboard side. It doesn't obviously do anything else, although it may be trying to do something I can't see. I can't see any conflicting keystrokes in the device configuration (and surely shift-[letter] would not be a viable keystroke combination?) It still occurs after restarting the tablet.
Interestingly I get the same result with my (Sony) phone, so I guess this is a keyboard or Android problem.
What do I need to do to be able to start a sentence with 'W' again?
